# problems importing a C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I am trying to access this C++ function from the C# code in my program

```
Tridiagonal3 (float** mat, float* diag, float* subd)
{
   float a = mat[0][0], b = mat[0][1], c = mat[0][2],
                        d = mat[1][1], e = mat[1][2],
                                       f = mat[2][2];

}
```

The call is as shown below

```
tred2(tensor, eigenValues, eigenVectors);
```

where tensor is `float[,]` and eigenvalues and eigenvectors are `float[]` arrays.

When i try doing this i get an exception

```
Access violation reading location 0x3f5dce99
```

when i try accessing

```
float a = mat[0][0]
```

What could be happening?

Comment: What do you pass in as parameters?  It looks like the array has not been allocated.

Comment: Why don't you post the call-site code? what is `float[,]` by the way?

Comment: @Nawaz: `float[,]` is a multi-dimensional array in C#.

Comment: @Nawaz: `float[,]` is a 2 dimensional array of `float`s

Comment: How can we possibly start answering this if you won't show us your P/Invoke code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tridiagonal3 (float** mat, float* diag, float* subd)`

mat is a double-pointer type (pointer to pointer).
In C#, float[,] is *not* a double-pointer. It's just syntactic sugar for accessing a multi-dimensional array, just like you would do `mat[x + y * width]` instead of `mat[y][x]`;

In other words, you are passing a `float*` to your C++ application, not a `float**`.

You should change the way you use `mat` to access elements using the *manual* offset, like `mat[y + 2 * x]`

Answer (score 0):

Either `mat` or `mat[0]` is a bad pointer. The problem lies in the code that allocates `mat`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first allocate an array with 3 pointers that can be done using a class:

```
class Pointer3
{
     IntPtr p1, p2, p3;
}
```

then you need to define a row using a class:

```
class Row3
{
     float a, b, c;
}
```

all that in C#. then you need to allocate them:

```
Row3 row1, row2, row3;
// todo: init values
Pointer3 mat;
// allocate place for the rows in the matrix
mat.p1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Row3));
mat.p2 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Row3));
mat.p3 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Row3));
// store the rows
Marshal.StructureToPtr(row1, mat.p1, false);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(row2, mat.p2, false);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(row3, mat.p3, false);
// allocate pointer for the matrix
IntPtr matPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Pointer3));
// store the matrix in the pointer
Marsha.StructureToPtr(mat, matPtr, false);
```

Now its safe to call the function using `matPtr` as the matrix.
To get the values out of the modified matrix:

```
Marshal.PtrToStructure(matPtr, mat);
```